# Scanner NextInt() using a comma separated coordinate

Tags: java, io

I am trying to parse information from a text file in the following format:

```
WarningGeotask: 0, 1
```

The first word is a keyword for a certain object to create at the coordinate location given in the numbers that follow it. Here is what my loop looks like currently:

```
// Open file and scan for a line
File f = new File("Simulation.Configuration");
Scanner s = new Scanner(f); 

while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    // Parse each line with a temporary scanner
    String line = s.nextLine();
    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(line);

    // Get keywords from the file to match to variable names
    String keyword = s2.next();

    //...Multiple if statements searching for different keywords...

    else if (keyword.equals("WarningGeotask:")) {
        int xCoord = s2.nextInt();
        int yCoord = s2.nextInt();

        WarningGeotask warningGeotask = new WarningGeotask(xCoord, yCoord);

        s2.close();
        continue;
    }
}
```

However, this code doesn't work properly. In fact, `String xCoord = s2.nextInt()` throws an error. I can do `s2.next()` and print out `s2.nextInt()` which returns 1. But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with Scanner to get 0 and 1 set to two different variables. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: The String variables xCoord and yCoord are supposed to be int - my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `split()`

when you read the lines, make it as Comma-separated value :

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = s.nextLine().replace(":",",");
   String[] data =line.split(",");
   //...Multiple if statements searching for different keywords
   else if(data[0].equals("WarningGeotask:")){
      WarningGeotask warningGeotask = new WarningGeotask(Integer.parseInt(data[1].trim()), Integer.parseInt[data[2].trim());
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that Scanner#nextInt() returns a numerical value (to be exact: a value of type int), which you try to assign to a String variable.

So instead of:

```
String xCoord = s2.nextInt();
String yCoord = s2.nextInt();
```

try:

```
int x = s2.nextInt();
int y = s2.nextInt();
```

Comment: It looks like this is the problem. Here is the documentation for Scanner and its nextInt() method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: Sorry, the `String` was a typo. Meant for `int` variables. Good catch though.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    sc.useDelimiter("\\D+");
    int n1 = sc.nextInt();
    int n2 = sc.nextInt();
```